# CSS Change background colour of an entire table row using :target selector

Tags: html, css, background-color

I have a table with multiple rows and 2 columns. I would like for a whole table row to change background colour when `#highlight:target` is used. I have been able to make individual cells change colour with `<td id="highlight">` but not on `<tr id="highlight">`

CSS:

```
#highlight:target {
  background-color: #FF9900;
  -webkit-transition: all 1s linear;
}
```

HTML:

```
<a href="#highlight">Highlight!!</a>
<table>
  <tr id="highlight">
    <td>First Column</td>
    <td>Second Column</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Can I change the background colour of an entire row using the `:target` selector?

Comment: [Works for me](http://jsfiddle.net/7dmc3oc1/)

Comment: @TinyGiant What web browser are you using?

Comment: Chrome, this will work on all browsers [unless you have a background set on the td element](http://jsfiddle.net/7dmc3oc1/1/) as the cell will be over top of the row.

Comment: I think the answer given by @tribe84 is the best for this situation as some of my tables do already have background styling.

Comment: Whatever you want to do, just stating that your MCVE works as is, so this isn't a real question.

Comment: Syntax ERROR! `<td>...</th>`

Comment: @Pangloss Woops ;) fixed lol

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to target the cell.

```
#highlight:target td {
  background-color: #FF9900;
  -webkit-transition: all 1s linear;
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Add below css in your style tag.

```
#highlight td {
  background-color: #FF9900;
  -webkit-transition: all 1s linear;
}
```

Comment: This is exactly the same as the accepted answer from 2015, except that it doesn't include the one thing OP asked for: using the `:target` selector.